# How do I find information on a relative born in Romania before it became a country?

Tags: 19th-century, birth-records, marriage-records, romania

My great-great grandfather, Wolf Finkelstein, was born in 1832 before Romania came into existence so, I don't know how to find out anything about him such as who his parents were.  I think he was born in a town called Jassy which I have also seen spelled Iasi.  Any help to point me in the right direction will be greatly appreciated.  Please note, I am new to using this site so, I may not always ask a question the best way.

Comment: There is no need to apologize for being new.  We are very glad to have you here and asking questions.  To learn about our site I recommend taking the 2-minute [Tour].  This question seems to just provide more details to [an earlier one that you posted](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/7975/where-in-romania-was-wolf-finkelstein-born) and so I am going to make it a Duplicate of that after copying those new details into it.  You could have done this yourself using the **edit** button beneath it but our processes take a little time to learn.

Comment: Do not be alarmed that the earlier question already has two answers.  You will probably see those revised and/or new answers added now that the additional information about your ancestor's possible birth location has become available.

Comment: The question "How to trace Romanian ancestry?" http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3706/how-to-trace-romanian-ancestry may also be of help